# Why no love for UX community bulletin?

Tags: feature-request, design

Can we at-least have some background color to highlight that it exists? I feel it will be a good start to divert traffic of regular users to the meta. Right now, it is quite hidden and can easily be overlooked in the pool of other things going around in its vicinity.

[image]

Compare this to other sites' bulletin (the standard Beta site bulletin is on the right):

[image]